# Sublime 2 less2css not compiling automatically

Tags: css, compilation, less, sublimetext2

When I save my style.less, the code isn't being auto-compiled. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Below is what I have in my ox.sublime-project file:

```
{
        "folders":
        [
            {
                "path": "projects/example/web"
            }
        ],
        "settings":
        {
            "less2css":
            {
                "autoCompile":true,
                "main_file":"/projects/example/web/style.less",
                "minify":false
            }
        }
    }
```

I see this in the console when I save my style.less:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Applications/Sublime
>   Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 574, in run_
>       return self.run(edit)
>   File "less2css in /Users/jlei/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed
>   Packages/Less2Css.sublime-package", line 57, in run
>   File
>   "lesscompiler in /Users/jlei/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Installed Packages/Less2Css.sublime-package", line 152, in
>   convert_one
>   File "lesscompiler in /Users/jlei/Library/Application
>   Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Less2Css.sublime-package",
>   line 254, in convertLess2Css
>   File "./python3.3/os.py", line 251, in
>   makedirs   File "./python3.3/os.py", line 251, in makedirs
>   File
>   "./python3.3/os.py", line 251, in makedirs
>   File "./python3.3/os.py",
>   line 262, in makedirs
>
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/projects'

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: which console are you referring to? the thing at the bottom of sublime? if so, no there is no conflict. it just says it's saving but it doesn't say it's compiling

Comment: From the application menu `View > Show Console`

Comment: Also, is `lessc`  installed on your system?

Comment: Do I need that? I thought I only need Less2Css? Also in the console I've edited it to include what I can in the console

Comment: I don't know, it says so in the README: "Requires lessc installed on PATH."

Comment: Ok I installed lessc and restarted sublime. Still doesn't work. Using Package Control shouldn't make a difference right?

Comment: According to the error log, you need to check your permissions for `/projects`. I've been wondering about the mismatch: `projects` vs `/projects`. I installed the package via Package Control and had no problems saving LESS as CSS (I didn't use a project file)

Comment: i changed the path and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be caused by the mismatch of path names? First, you're using `"projects/example/web"`, later it's `"/projects/example/web/style.less"`(note the leading slash).